# Contadores de rendimiento SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, grafana

Necesito monitorear los Batch Requests & el numero de transacciones que recibe mi instancia.

He estado revisando y con la siguiente consulta obtengo la información desde SQL Server

```
DECLARE @DATE datetime
SELECT @DATE = create_date FROM sys.databases
WHERE name ='tempdb'
SELECT cntr_value / datediff (second,@DATE,getdate()) as [Batch Requests/sec]
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name  like '%Batch Requests/se%'
```

Pero al pasarla a Grafana obtengo el error "Data does not have a time field".

Me pueden asesorar si necesito utilizar algún parámetro extra, por favor?

Comment: No tengo ni idea, pero observo que el error dice que el recordset no tiene una columna de fecha y la consulta efectivamente no la tiene, ¿Por que no pruebas agregar una columna nueva con la fecha a tu query?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho , gracias por la observación.  No lo había tomado en cuenta pero efectivamente grafana necesitaba otro campo fecha para graficar la información.